# z3 enumsort exception after version 4.12.0

Tags: z3, z3py

After I upgrade z3 to version 4.12.0, exception happened when declarating an EnumSort again in a function.

Is it normal or a defect?

```
from z3 import *


def enum_decl():
    Color, (red, green, blue) = EnumSort('Color', ['red', 'green', 'blue'])


enum_decl()
# invoke again, raise exception of "enumeration sort name is already declared"
enum_decl()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a deliberate change, put in on November 19, 2022: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blame/e8a38c548235d21c9f075cc9cdbe473fc68ef8bd/src/api/api_datatype.cpp#L108

And indeed this is desirable. As a worse example, consider:

```py
from z3 import *

Color, (red, green, blue) = EnumSort('Color', ['red', 'green', 'blue'])

# Code using red/green/blue as Color

# Later, declare again:
Color, (purple, white)    = EnumSort('Color', ['purple', 'white'])

# Code using purple/white as Color
```

If you were to allow repetitions like this, you'd have an inconsistent state of affairs. In any z3 context, there's only one namespace for sort names, so you cannot have a redefinition. (At least not without doing a whole lot of internal rewriting.) And such a redeclaration is most likely a programming error anyhow, so they put in a check to avoid mistaken uses of it.

Do you have an actual use case for being able to redeclare an enum-sort? Such declarations are usually either done at the top-level (i.e., once), or in some class-initializer anyhow; to avoid such clashes.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have an actual use case. In our bounded model checker(BMC), we have many goals to check. For each goal, we need to add the constraints to z3, and declare sort names that constraints needed.  Then the exception happens. If we can only declare a sort name once，is there someway to destroy  it after the end of check?

Comment: There’s no way to “destroy” it. Here’s one way you can deal with it. Simply keep a global variable yourself, setting it to true after the first time, and skip the declaration if you find it already set in subsequent calls. This assumes the enumeration stays exactly the same. If not, then you’ll have to use a unique name.

Comment: We have different models with specific goals to check. The models are generated and we can't control the names used in the models. So we have to declare model related variables, sort names and constraints, again and again.  I think a global variable can't solve my issue.  I have tried to find method to reset the context of z3 but failed. Hope  some other ideas, thanks

Comment: Btw, from the beginning, if I redeclare the same sort name, it may be a programming error, or maybe not.  It should be the responsibility of users. A warning maybe enough, why raise exception?

Comment: Looking at the old code in z3, it was simply ignoring subsequent definitions of the same name. So, if the enumeration was changing then you already had a bug. Thus the new exception isn’t any worse, in fact it’s better.  Instead of resetting the context, you should create a brand new solver each time. (That is, if definitions are changing, don’t use the solver incrementally.)

Comment: Yes. I do create a new solver each time, but the enumeration declared is still there. I don't understand the scope of enumeration in z3. I declare an enum name in a function of a class. I create a new object of the class and declare the enum name again, why  the enumeration declared is still there？

Comment: I think your best bet is to create a new context each time, instead of relying on the global context. This is a bit ugly since you have to now pass your newly created context to all the functions that take a context parameter; and it's easy to miss all the cases. Also, probably not the most efficient, since context creation is an expensive operation.

Comment: Thansk, helpful. Perhaps I have to create a new context with a lot of related changes by now. Although, still I think, why not just use new declared enumeration sort to replace the old one?